# Why the add or the imul get wrong results in nested loops in x86-64

Tags: linux, x86, x86-64, nasm

I am implementing at least 3 nested loops in x86-64 using the NASM assembler, and to see how they are working Im creating a counter and printing its values for each iteration. The issue comes when the second iteration of the external loop begins because ist not setting the register counter to 0. Ive tried `mov rbp, 0`, `xor rbp, rbp` and `sub rbp, 10` but all the results that may be less than 8 are worng for example if the result must be a `0` its shown as a `10`.Here`s my code:

test.asm

```
global main

section .data
    newLine db 10,0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov r12, 0
    mov rbp, 0
    jmp t1

b1:
    mov r13, 0
    jmp t2

b2:
    mov r14, 0
    jmp t3

b3:
    printVal rbp
    print newLine
    inc r14

t3:
    cmp r14, 3
    jl b3

    add rbp, 6
    inc r13
t2:
    cmp r13, 3
    jl b2

    inc r12
    mov rbp, 0
    xor rbp, rbp
    print newLine
t1:
    cmp r12, 2
    jl b1
    exit
```

Result

```
0
0
0
6
6
6
12
12
12

10
10
10
16
16
16
12
12
12
```

Expected Result

```
0
0
0
6
6
6
12
12
12

0
0
0
6
6
6
12
12
12
```

linux64.inc

```
section .bss
    digitSpace resb 100
    digitSpacePos resb 8
    printSpace resb 8
%macro print 1
    mov rax, %1
    mov [printSpace], rax
    mov rbx, 0
%%printLoop:
    mov cl, [rax]
    cmp cl, 0
    je %%endPrintLoop
    inc rbx
    inc rax
    jmp %%printLoop
%%endPrintLoop:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, [printSpace]
    mov rdx, rbx
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro printVal 1
    mov rax, %1
%%printRAX:
    mov rcx, digitSpace
    mov [digitSpacePos], rcx

%%printRAXLoop:
    mov rdx, 0
    mov rbx, 10
    div rbx
    push rax
    add rdx, 48

    mov rcx, [digitSpacePos]
    mov [rcx], dl
    inc rcx
    mov [digitSpacePos], rcx

    pop rax
    cmp rax, 0
    jne %%printRAXLoop

%%printRAXLoop2:
    mov rcx, [digitSpacePos]

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, rcx
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall

    mov rcx, [digitSpacePos]
    dec rcx
    mov [digitSpacePos], rcx

    cmp rcx, digitSpace
    jge %%printRAXLoop2

%endmacro

%macro exit 0
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
%endmacro
```

sh

```
#!/bin/bash
nasm -f elf64 test.asm -o test.o
ld test.o -o test
./test
```

Comment: Newline has value `10`.  This looks suspiciously like you're overwriting your counter with a newline somehow, but I don't see where.  Single-step your asm with a debugger (like GDB) to see when RBP becomes `10`.  (If ever).  Your loops look fine I think, so I don't trust that rats nest of macros.  That's what debuggers are for.

Comment: The problem isn’t the value of rbp. I think there’s something wrong in the print routine. It think once it prints a two digit number, it keeps printing the first digit in front of each single digit number.

Comment: @prl, good call: `printRAX` steps `[digitSpacePos]` *after* depositing each digit, and *should* therefore step back *before* fetching each digit to print -- the end condition of the print loop is then `[digitSpacePos]` == `digitSpace`.